# Add a column for category after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to groupby and get the another column containing category of groupby:
This is my input

```
x=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'B': ['w', 'x', 'w', 'y']})
```

I expect this to be the output:

```
y=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'B': ['w', 'x', 'w', 'y'], 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C0', 'C2']})
```

I have tried this:

```
'C' + nlp.groupby(['HCCTrack (S)', 'AdditionalCodes (S)']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) instead [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
x['C'] = 'C' + x.groupby(['A', 'B']).ngroup().astype(str)
print (x)
   A  B   C
0  a  w  C0
1  b  x  C1
2  a  w  C0
3  c  y  C2
```